# Storing Variables in a Class

Tags: arduino

I am trying to keep track of a set of data by declaring a class.
The class is initialized with a unique ID but then fills the rest of the variables out later in the code after some calculations.

First, is that even an acceptable way to do this?
Second, I'm trying to pass it a char array but it does not want to take the value. Is this the correct way to define the fileName and call it back when creating the file?

Here's the example, I define a variable from the Customer class then try to store its filename:

```
#ifndef customer_h
#define customer_h

class Customer
  {
public:
  Customer (char *number);
  char *ID;
  double current;
  double voltage;
  double powerConsumption;
  double remainingCredit;
  int relay;
  char *lastName;
  char *firstName;
  char *fileName;

private:
  }; 
Customer::Customer(char *number)
  {
    ID = number;
  } 
#endif

void setup()
{
cust1.fileName = getFileName(cust1.ID);
}


char *getFileName(char *customerID)
{

  char *charID;
  String newID;

  for (int i = strlen(customerID)-4; i<= strlen(customerID)-1; i++)
{
  newID += customerID[i];
}
  newID += ".csv";
  int lenID = newID.length() + 1;
  char fileName[lenID];
  newID.toCharArray(fileName,lenID);

  return fileName;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help and info you can provide!

Comment: And what makes you think this is C code?

Answer (score 0):

Be better to use a structured rather than a class. They are pretty similar but in this case seems like a structure will be much better go and read about the differences and you'll see

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. In fact, I didn't even have to change the rest of the code, just the definition and declaration. Everything else just falls in place! Thank you!

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped!